# Area 51 badge descriptions need updating now that the on/off-topic voting has gone

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, badge-description

Now that the voting on Area 51 has changed from on-topic/off-topic/not a good question, to up/down, there are several [badge descriptions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges) that are out of date:

- **Advocate**         First on-topic or off-topic vote
- **Centrist**         First question with 3 on-topic votes
- **Good Question**    Question with 30 on-topic or off-topic votes
- **Great Question**   Question with 50 on-topic or off-topic votes
- **Nice Question**    Question with 10 on-topic or off-topic votes
- **Radical**      First question with 3 off-topic votes

Please can they be updated to reflect the new voting mechanism?

Comment: They don't just need new descriptions, I believe they need new mechanisms.  Off-topic votes are now votes to close, and there's max 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Area 51's badges have been updated to reflect the [recent voting changes](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/announcement-changes-to-area-51-voting):

- **Advocate**: First up vote
- **Centrist**: First question with a score of 3 or more
- **Good Question**: Question score of 30 or more
- **Great Question**: Question score of 50 or more
- **Nice Question**: Question score of 10 or more
- **Radical**: *hidden from the [badges](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges) page, but still shown on the profiles of users that earned it*

We also took this opportunity to make an attempt at backfilling "badge reasons", so certain badges now show the proposals for which the badge was earned, e.g. the [Revolution](http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/22/revolution) badge.